# Why is ProducerTemplate's method sendBody not returning in integration test?

Tags: apache-camel, junit5, spring-boot-test

I want to test one Apache Camel route in a Spring Boot integration test, but the integration test doens't finish. [`ProducerTemplate#sendBody`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-api/3.5.0/org/apache/camel/ProducerTemplate.html#sendBody-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) doesn't return.

**Spring Boot application**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public EndpointRouteBuilder routeBuilder() {
    return new EndpointRouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(direct("in")).multicast().to(direct("route"), direct("request"));
        from(direct("route")).setHeader("id", constant("1")).to(direct("aggregate"));
        from(direct("response")).log("Response: ${body}").to(direct("aggregate"));
        from(direct("aggregate"))
            .log("Aggregation-In: ${body}")
            .aggregate(header("id"), AggregationStrategies.useLatest())
            .completionSize(2)
            .log("Aggregation-out: ${body}")
            .to(direct("out"));
      }
    };
  }
}
```

**Spring Boot integration test**

```java
@SpringBootTest
@CamelSpringBootTest
@MockEndpointsAndSkip("(direct:request|direct:out)")
class TextRouteBuilderIT {

  @EndpointInject("mock:direct:out")
  private MockEndpoint outRoute;

  @EndpointInject("direct:response")
  private Endpoint responseRoute;

  @EndpointInject("mock:direct:request")
  private MockEndpoint requestRoute;

  @Autowired private ProducerTemplate template;

  @Test
  void test() throws CamelExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    requestRoute.whenAnyExchangeReceived(
        new Processor() {
          @Override
          public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            exchange.getIn().setBody("Response");
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("id", "1");
            responseRoute.createProducer().process(exchange);
          }
        });

    template.sendBody("direct:in", "test");
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }
}
```

**Logs**

```
o.a.c.t.s.j.CamelAnnotationsHandler      : Enabling auto mocking and skipping of endpoints matching pattern [(direct:request|direct:out)] on CamelContext with name [camelContext].
c.t.s.j.CamelSpringBootExecutionListener : CamelSpringBootExecutionListener before: class test.TextRouteBuilderIT.test
c.t.s.j.CamelSpringBootExecutionListener : Initialized CamelSpringBootExecutionListener now ready to start CamelContext
o.a.c.t.s.j.CamelAnnotationsHandler      : Starting CamelContext with name [camelContext].
.i.e.InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy : Adviced endpoint [direct://request] with mock endpoint [mock:direct:request]
.i.e.InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy : Adviced endpoint [direct://out] with mock endpoint [mock:direct:out]
o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.5.0 (camel-1) is starting
o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Using HealthCheck: camel-spring-boot
o.a.c.p.aggregate.AggregateProcessor     : Defaulting to MemoryAggregationRepository
o.a.c.i.e.InternalRouteStartupManager    : Route: route1 started and consuming from: direct://in
o.a.c.i.e.InternalRouteStartupManager    : Route: route2 started and consuming from: direct://route
o.a.c.i.e.InternalRouteStartupManager    : Route: route3 started and consuming from: direct://response
o.a.c.i.e.InternalRouteStartupManager    : Route: route4 started and consuming from: direct://aggregate
o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Total 4 routes, of which 4 are started
o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.5.0 (camel-1) started in 0.015 seconds
route4                                   : Aggregation-In: test
route3                                   : Response: Response
route4                                   : Aggregation-In: Response
route4                                   : Aggregation-out: Response
```

It looks like the last route is finished, but the Spring Boot integration test is still running. The `RuntimeException` is not thrown.

**Research**

I followed

- [Testing the JUnit 5 way](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/spring-boot.html#_testing_the_junit_5_way)
- [Annotation Type MockEndpointsAndSkip](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-test-spring/3.5.0/org/apache/camel/test/spring/MockEndpointsAndSkip.html)

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score -1):

intercept the route that already has the response grouped, capture the exchange and return. I managed to make this return with the completeblefuture method complete

Comment: Could you show your code?